# Several items in label for select form in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `select` form in Vue.js. In the options, it shows the list of users with fields like name and telephone.
Now, I can display only one field in label - `telephone` in this case. How can I display several fields? For example, the `name` and the `telephone`.

```
<selector placeholder="Выбрать"
  :options="usersList"
  track-by="id"
  label="telephone"
  v-model="user"
  :allow-empty="false"
>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the `<option>` tags like so:

```
<select v-model=...>
  <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.id">
    {{ item.telephone }} and {{ item.other_fields }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can render through the list using v-for looping with your **option** tag.

Go through

https://alligator.io/vuejs/iterating-v-for/

and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html (Vuejs documention)

It will help you to better understand the concepts of v-for.